# Horror movie in a subway

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, horror

I remember watching a horror movie a long time ago. In it, a group of people is trapped in a subway for some reason. They are pursued and killed off by what looks like either some kind of intelligent zombie or a horribly mutilated human.

Anyway, I remember that two of the main characters were a woman whose name I can't remember, and a man named Jimmy who I think was a policeman.

At some point, those two are captured by the creature and placed into two cages that are mostly filled with water. The woman remarks that the walls of the cage that separate them don't go all the way to the bottom, so it would be possible to swim underneath them. Jimmy remarks that he can't hold his breath.

I don't remember what happens next. There was also a jumpscare scene where either the aforementioned woman or a different one is sitting in the darkness with just a flashlight on, turns the flashlight towards her face, and suddenly the creature's face appears in the light.

I think, near the end, either these two or some other people end up killing the creature either by choking it to death or drowning it in a sink, and its last words were exactly what one of its previous victims said. In the dub I watched, it spoke using the previous victim's voice as well, although I don't know if that's just how the dub went or if that was also the case in the original version.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sounds like ***[Creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creep_(2004_film))*** (2004).

> *Creep* is a 2004 horror film written and directed by Christopher Smith. The film follows a woman locked in the London Underground overnight who finds herself being stalked by a hideously deformed killer living in the sewers below. The film was first shown at the Frankfurt Fantasy Filmfest in Germany on 10 August 2004.

There's definitely a scene like the one you described with the cages in water, and the killer is a bald, mutant man, the result of some sort of secret experiment with babies. Also, the Wikipedia cast credits list a character named Jimmy.

Answer (score 6):

I think this could be [Death Line](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068458/reference) from 1972 with Donald Pleasence. It's also set in the London Underground and the only phrase that the killer can say is "Mind the Doors!" (a recorded warning to passengers boarding the trains). Creep sounds like a remake.